# jquery .show() not working on ASP MVC 3 fieldsets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Below is the jquery I'm using to cycle through a group of `fieldset` elements and, based upon the user's selection from a group of radio buttons, decide which one should be visible and which should be hidden (they are all hidden when the page loads). However, I can't get the `.show()` method to work.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function () {
        var radioValue = $(this);
        var elements = [];

        $('#RightDiv').children().each(function () {
            console.log(radioValue.attr('id') + " " + $(this).attr('id'));
            if (radioValue.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id')) {
                console.log('here');
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ASP MVC**

```
<div id="LeftDiv" style="width:450px;float:left;">
    <fieldset style="width:350px;">
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "Enroll" }) Enroll a Tax ID for EFT <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "New" }) New Tax ID Without EFT Enrollment <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "ModT" }) Modify EFT Information by Tax ID <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "ModA" }) Modify EFT Information by Agent ID <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "Clone" }) Clone EFT on to a Sub Agent ID <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("TransactionType", false, new { @id = "Unenroll" }) Unenroll EFT by Tax ID 
    </fieldset>        
</div
<div id="RightDiv" style="width:420px;float:left;">
    <fieldset id="Enroll" style="width:350px; visibility: hidden;">...</fieldset> 
    <fieldset id="New" style="width:350px; visibility: hidden;">...</fieldset>   
    <fieldset id="ModT" style="width:350px; visibility: hidden;">...</fieldset>
    <fieldset id="Clone" style="width:350px; visibility: hidden;">...</fieldset> 
    <fieldset id="Unenroll" style="width:350px; visibility: hidden;">...</fieldset>                 
</div>
```

Here's a screen shot of the console readout from the jquery loop

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `visibility: hidden;` of your fieldsets to `display: none;`.

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.show()` only knows how to deal with the `display` property of CSS per the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/) so for that code to work you either need to use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;` or use `jQuery.attr()` to edit the style attribute.