# Hide/Show Placeholder using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, show-hide, asp.net-placeholder

I have a placeholder and want to show it using JQuery. Now in placeholder I cannot have `style="Visibility:hidden"` so I have to set the `Visible` Property to `False`, hence Jquery not able to find it.

My question is how do I set the visibility on JQuery load function instead, have tried following with no success(**bare in mind my controls have this extra characters at beginning so need by ClientID**):

```
 $('div[id*=phAdd]').hide();
 $('div[id$=phAdd]').hide();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326031/jquery-show-not-working-on-asp-mvc-3-fieldsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this Placeholder not being found is because of this line

```
`Visible="false"`
```

while defining the `ASP.NET control`

`Visible="false"` does not render the element in the First place. 
So you have no way of selecting it.  Instead remove that line and add a Class to it which has the display property set.

So by doing this the element will be available on the `DOM` and your selector should work fine.

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ClassName="hide"
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it says  Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder' does not have a public property named 'ClassName'.

Comment: Is there anyway to add css to placeholder? I cannot see any options

Comment: ok added a <div id="myid" style="display: none"> around the placeholder and seems to work to show/hide the div.

Comment: oops.. It should be `CssClass` instead of `ClassName`